# Swt table getData() to string list

Tags: java, list, swt

I have populated swt Table and it displays it OK, but now I want to get data from swt Table to

Is there any solution to get data to array or list from table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
TableItem[] tableItems = table.getItems();
```

to get the the value of the first row at the 2nd column

```
tableItems[0].getText(1)
```

You might want to look into JFace TableViewer to make this easier.