# How to get Values from table and set to a list in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have a table with 3 columns say type,name and value.

For example my table has the following values:

> ```
> Type     Name    Value
> +++++++++++++++++++++++
> Int       id       0
> String   name     null
> ```

How to get these values from the table and set to a list.

---

```
TableItem[] items = voTable.getItems();

List<VogenBean> lstTableValue = new ArrayList<VogenBean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Items length--" + items.length);
        VogenBean bean = new VogenBean();
        bean.setClassName(domainName);
        bean.setAttrName(typeLabel.getText());
        bean.setMethodName(nameLabel.getText());
        bean.setAttrInit(valueLabel.getText());
        /*
         * tableValue = domainName + ":" + typeLabel.getText() + ":" +
         * nameLabel.getText()+":"+valueLabel.getText();
         * System.out.println("Value--"+tableValue);
         */
        lstTableValue.add(bean);
    }

    for (Iterator iterator = lstTableValue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        VogenBean vo = (VogenBean) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Class Name--" + vo.getClassName());
        System.out.println("Attr Name--" + vo.getAttrName());
        System.out.println("Method Name--" + vo.getMethodName());
        System.out.println("Attr Init--" + vo.getAttrInit());

    }

    return lstTableValue;
```

This is my code. I'm getting only last field in the table. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swt table getData() to string list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973826/swt-table-getdata-to-string-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of a certain row in table based on selection, you can use [`Table#getSelection()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#getSelection%28%29). In case you are using a `TableViewer`, you have to do a [`TableViewer#getSelection()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/StructuredViewer.html#getSelection%28%29).

But if you want to just iterate through a table and get all values, just use [`Table#getItems()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#getItems%28%29). Each item is a `TableItem` and you can get values for each column by using [`TableItem#getText(int columnIndex)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TableItem.html#getText%28int%29).

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm using Table Item But only the values in the last row is alone getting set to the list.How to select all rows in a table and set to a list.

Comment: What kind of list are you using and what are you using to add to the list? Are you using `Table#getItems()` to iterate through all the rows of the table?